# INDEX(FILTER(SORT not solving - Need an alternative?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, indexing, filter

Purpose: I'm trying to fetch the value from column c in the first sheet,  where column a matches to column a in current sheet. If there are more than one matches in column a, fetch the most recent entry, according to the date in column b. If the most recent cell in column c was left blank, go back and fetch from the most recent matching row in which column c contains a value.

See the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6N6YAV3nL1OmlbDVOvED9ltORNEZYvnqqkt97cLLsE/edit), it's pretty clear.

I tried: `=INDEX(FILTER(SORT('VISIT LOG'!C2:C,'VISIT LOG'!B2:B,FALSE),'VISIT LOG'!A2:A=A2,'VISIT LOG'!C2:C<>""),1,1)`

But it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A2:A),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,SORT(LAMBDA(z,FILTER(z,INDEX(z,,3)<>""))('Visit log'!A2:C),2,0),3,)),))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the column numbers from static (3) to dynamic? In case the original columns get rearranged

Answer (score 1):

You can try with QUERY and MAP:

```
=MAP(A2:A,C2:C,LAMBDA(ax,cx,IF(ax="","",QUERY('Visit log'!A2:C,"Select C where C is not null AND A = '"&ax&"' order by B desc limit 1"))))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. You're great! However one of the names in column A had an apostrophe (e.g. O'Brien) and the query didn't know how to parse that, until I removed the apostrophy